# DS-160 - B1/B2 visa - Work/Education/Training - How to fill the section as full-time employee and part-time student

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, applications

I'm currently trying to fill up DS-160 form, but I got stuck on the *Work / Education / Training* section. I'm working full-time and studying as part-time student. I didn't graduate yet and have changed from full-time to part-time studies one and a half year ago. How should I fill this section? If I put work as primary occupation there is no place I can add any information about studies - I can't put them in the previous section as I haven't graduated yet and the date attended to must be in the past.

Any ideas how to fill this section?

Should I split the full-time and the part-time studies? This would let me put the full-time studies as a separate education entry, but the problem is I didn't graduate.

Should I just omit the studies completely and give high school as my last education?

Comment: There's nothing in this question about immigration. Closing it as such seems inappropriate.

Comment: I agree... This is about filling a form for non immigration visa to be able to go on a business trip.

Comment: Agreed. Having said that, the question should explicitly state what kind of visa is being applied for. The DS-160 is used for different visas (I filled one in for a J visa for a visit that would definitely have been off-topic, here) and people shouldn't have to infer what the question is about from reading the tags.